# Show $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \cos(nx)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Show $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$
>   $\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \cos(nx)$, is continuous on
>   $\mathbb{R}$.

Proof:

Let $r \gt 0$ be some fixed number. Then for $x \in [-r, r]$,
$\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \cos(nx) \leq \frac{r}{n^2}$, since $\sin(a) \leq |a|$ and $\cos(b) \leq 1$.

So define $M_n = \frac{r}{n^2}$, then $\sum_n M_n \lt \infty$, so by Weierstrass M test, $f$ uniformly converges on $[-r,r]$ and hence, continuous.

Since $r$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Edit: I would like proof verification and some feedback on my proof. Possibly a better proof.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you want to write $|\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) \cos(nx)| \leq \frac{r}{n^2}$ instead of what you had written, otherwise you are not bounding the sequence, similarly you want to write $|\sin(a)|\le|a|$ and $|\cos(nx)|\le 1$

Comment: @zhw, I would like some proof verification and suggestion.